# Mysql dump table by table in .sql files

Tags: mysql, dump

Is there a way via console to dump all tables of a database one by one? I want only to import some of them in staging area and some local but not export most of the tables twice (I need once 70% and once 80% of the database).

Comment: Write a script to get all the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, then dump each to its own file.

Comment: I have done it where I use a `LIKE` to get a list of table, then dump them all into one .sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper/releases) does this by default. It writes two files for every table dumped:

- database.table.sql(.gz)
- database.table-schema.sql(.gz)

Where `database` and `table` are the names of your database and each table.

If you want to do this with mysqldump, it's awkward. Possible solutions:

- Use mysqldump with the `--tables` option to specify a subset of tables.
- Use the `--tab` option to dump CSV files, one per table.
- Use `sed` or `perl` or some other text filtering tool to separate the tables you want from your single dump file.

Comment: Too bad - our hoster will not allow non-ubuntu core repos. Maybe a nice touch for local setups. Export of 1.6GB DB in 7s and import in 5min. Pretty fast.